# Trying to translate this line of Python to Java- getting different answers

Tags: java, python, security, hex, hashcode

Original Python code:

```
import hashlib    
return int(hashlib.md5("string").hexdigest(), 16) % 100
```

My attempt to translate into Java:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.math.*;    

String s = "string";
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());
BigInteger i = BigInteger(1,m.digest());
return i % 100;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You like the comfort of Python but you want a Java project? Try Jython.

Comment: You haven't specified the character set in either case. Are you sure that both python and java are using the same character encoding to produce the byte sequence from the string? I believe python will always use UTF-8, but I think java uses the system locale character set.

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't even tried to compile this code, since it's not working. BigInteger isn't a primitive type, therefore `%` operator doesn't work. You should use `.mod` method instead.

Your code, fixed:

```
String s = "string";
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
return i.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
```

And since you're updating 0 - s.length(), you can just pass all the bytes to `m.digest`, make it one line shorter:

```
String s = "string";
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1, m.digest(s.getBytes()));
return i.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
```

And if you really want an one-liner... **Warning, highly unreadable**:

```
return new BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest( s.getBytes()) ).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

It's always recommended to specify the encoding of the input string while converting to byte stream.

Without specifying an encoding scheme, programming language implementations are free to choose their default format. This can vary across programming languages and even across different versions of the same programming language.

### Python

An advantage of python is, [the ability to handle arbitrarily large integer values](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#integer-objects)

```py
import hashlib


data: str = "string"
print(int(hashlib.md5(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) % 100)
```

### Java

[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) is needed to deal with `long` values outside the [Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) boundaries.

MessageDigest instances are not thread safe, so use with care(new instances or ThreadLocal) in multithreaded use cases.

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class TestMD5 {

    private static final String DIGEST_ALGO = "MD5";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = "string";
        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST_ALGO).digest(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        int value = new BigInteger(1, digest).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(100)).intValueExact();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Both these solutions will print `81` for the given input `string`

### Note

- The implementation can print the same value for the given input `string` even without adding the encoding. It should not relied upon as this string is within the `ascii` range.
- Even for unicode character set, it is recommended to specify encoding as the same code point can be encoded in different encoding schemes like `utf-8`, `utf-16`
- while converting a byte stream to string, always specify the (de)encoding scheme